# Why does Ruby on Rails use "link_to ... method: :delete"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just started learning Ruby on Rails and it's a newbie question.

I did

```
$ rails generate scaffold Product blah blah...
```

and here is the snippet from the scaffold-generated view files.

```
<td class="list_actions">
<a href="/products/1">Show</a><br/>
<a href="/products/1/edit">Edit</a><br/>
<a href="/products/1" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
</td>
```

My question is,

Why does Ruby on Rails generate the link for "Destory" in this way? Changing method to "HTTP DELETE"...and all that.

Instead of doing it in more straight-forward way, 
i.e.

```
<a href="/products/1/delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Destroy</a>
```

Comment: if a google-bot issues a GET request to crawl your website, it might end up deleting all your products!

Comment: @daniel nub question. do bots only crawl links with a method of GET (not POST, DELETE, PUT, etc)?

Comment: yea bots normally only issue GET requests, although it seem Googlebot is experimenting with POST requests [http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's being semantic.

Although web-browsers generally only send HTTP GET and POST requests, the semantic intention of the requests is that they map one-to-one with [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) verbs:

- POST   <-> Create
- GET    <-> Read
- PUT    <-> Update
- DELETE <-> Delete

... and, from a practical viewpoint, resourceful routes reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Because by default you have [such routes for the resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) and by default DELETE method is used for destroy action and PUT method is used for update. so if you make the link this way:

```
<a href="/products/1/delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Destroy</a>
```

than it will point to GET action for the url `/products/:id/delete` and will work only if you define that route in the `routes.rb` file